# Is the Azure App Registration ownership sufficient for resetting client secrets?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

My App Registration - let's call it CHILD - has two owners. A human owner and another App Registration (here PARENT) as a second owner.

My goal is that both entities (human owner and PARENT App Registration) can reset the CHILD App Registration client secret. Whereas this works for the human owner, it does not work for the PARENT App Registration via CLI:

```
$ az ad app credential reset --id xxxxxxxx-062c-4251-86e7-xxxxxxxxxxxx --append
Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

I've double-checked that I'm really logged in as the PARENT App Registration into the `az` cli.

Is there another condition I'm overlooking? Is the App Registration ownership alone a sufficient requirement for client secret rotation?

Comment: what do you mean by parent app registration ?

Comment: As we're talking about App Registration owned by another App Registration, I labeled them PARENT (owner App Reg) and CHILD (owned App Reg) so that it's clear to which I'm referring to.

Comment: What are the MS Graph permissions for the parent app reg ?

Comment: Is that the `API Permissions` view in the App Registration pane of the relevant subject? Or the Graph permissions are to be found elsewhere?
In the `API Permissions` I can find just `User.Read`.

Comment: yep this one. you would need the `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` permission. see reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-4

Answer (score 0):

There is a blade in the Azure Portal under **Azure Active Directory** > **App Registrations** > [**Your app**] > **Roles and administrators** that shows a list of the roles that can manage the app. This includes also managing the secrets I think.

By default the **Cloud application administrator** role is listed.

Membership of the Cloud application administrator-role can be managed through **Azure Active Directory** > **Roles and administrators**.